# Choose separate file or combined file for bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What the best for separated file (every file js : alert.js; slide.js; etc) or combined file (bootstrap.min.js)?

Where I can find to download for the every separated file of bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to @user3173602's comment, you can use the [Customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to choose which plugins you would like to include, saves you searching them out manually. It will generate a minified and non-minified file for you.

Comment: hmmm, do separated js is more light than combined js? I mean, in combined js, we not use all of the javascript but in separated js, we can call js if need it. What do you think?

Comment: 1 javascript file would mean that you are only sending one request and not multiple requests for multiple files - which will increase the load time of the page slightly. There are a few questions similar to this with some better answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236767/one-big-javascript-file-or-multiple-smaller-files
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8978184/3172872

Answer (score 1):

it is much better to use the combined `bootstrap.min.js` file as it saves bandwidth and performance, but if you need a specific module like alert.js only, it much better to include the modules you will use (in this case you only include the alert.js file).
you can find the separate js files in the twitter bootstrap github repo, more specifically you can find them [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/js)

Comment: hmmm, do separated js is more light than combined js? I mean, in combined js, we not use all of the javascript but in separated js, we can call js if need it. What do you think?